# Jquery 4 images gallery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a gallery of 4 images. When the mouseenter, the images increase slightly. It's working, but the images are not scaling up or down proportionally. The images don't scale back to it's original size, which is (h)200px (w)267px. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $('.image').width(267);
           $('.image').mouseenter(function()
           {
              $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
              $(this).animate({width: "60%", height:"60%"}, 'slow');
           });

        $('.image').mouseleave(function()
          {   
              $(this).animate({width: "267px"}, 'slow');
           });
       });

      </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Gallery Test</h2>
      <hr />
      <div id="content">
      </div>
      <div id="gallery">
        <img class="image" src="images/one.jpg" height="200px" width="267px">
        <img class="image" src="images/two.jpg" height="200px" width="267px">
        <img class="image" src="images/three.jpg" height="200px" width="267px">
        <img class="image" src="images/four.jpg" height="200px" width="267px">
      </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote some messy code :) I'd take a little time to format it properly:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = 267;
    var height = 200;
    var w2 = width*0.6;
    var h2 = height*0.6;
    var image = $('.image');
    image.css({
        width:width,
        cursor: pointer,
    });

    image.on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: w2, height:h2}, 'slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: width, height:height}, 'slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Magic `stop(true,true)` function will do the job. You need to remove animation queue and stop current animation (two trues). If you do that, the animation will go smoothly and sweety.

Another bug in your code was setting width and height by percent. In the middle of animation there will be different base width than in time when animation finishes. That's why I declared local variables.

One more thing, remember: **local variables are your best friends**. Use them every time you need to use something more than once. When you write `$('.image')` it takes relative ages first to find every class in the DOM and then create a set of big and fat jQuery objects every time you call selector. The problem is with class searching on the whole document and creating set of jQuery objects more than once. At least narrow the selector search with something like this if you can:

```
 $("#imageContainer").find(".image")
```

Comment: All I have to say is Wow. I am going to go over it and see if I can understand what you wrote. The stop(true,true) is a little confusing. Thanks!

Comment: stop(true,true) is needed to avoid 'jumping queue' of a few animations when you wave your cursor over the images. Animations won't finish and will go back to their base size immediately.

Comment: It's still a bit jumpy. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

It's still a little jumpy. I even reduced the size of the images, assuming that was the issue. It's not smooth when I hover across all the images. That's when it gets jumpy. The images start flickering. Any idea why this is happening?

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var width = 100;
    var height = 134;
    var w2 = width*2;
    var h2 = height*2;
    var image = $('.image');
    image.css({
        width:"width",cursor: "pointer"});

    image.on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: w2, height:h2}, 'slow');
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            $(this).stop(true,true).animate({width: width, height:height}, 'slow');
        }
    });
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>IT 411</h1>

  <hr />
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <img class="image" src="images/one.jpg" height="134px" width="100px">
    <img class="image" src="images/two.jpg" height="134px" width="100px">
    <img class="image" src="images/three.jpg" height="134px" width="100px">
    <img class="image" src="images/four.jpg" height="134px" width="100px">
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have an error in declaration of size of the images. `width` and `height` attributes should be unitless (`width="267"`)

Comment: Also you made a bug in Javascript: `width:width` not `width:"width"`. I answered correctly and you rewrote with a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I redid it again. It's working smoothy now. Thanks again for taking a look at it.